# API minimize data usage

Tags: java, android, performance, api

I'm making games app on android using RAWG Video Games Database.

[This is how the app look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62G8p.jpg)

the problem is the API provide large image size average 1.5 MB,
it's too big for small size space in the app, and lots of data wasted.

all the solutions i found was for better performance "after downloading" the image
by scale down the resolution.

is there anyway i can make the image smaller "before download"?
or is there other APIs provide me small image for thumbnail and  another one as original size?

Comment: `is there anyway i can make the image smaller "before download"?` this is what the server is giving you, without changing the actual content on the server, no. `or is there other APIs provide me small image for thumbnail and another one as original size?` this is off-topic

Comment: check libraries like picasso or glide, they give you option to resize image when after downloading. So still data will be consumed but hopefully images won't take a lot of device storage. you also might want to look into this for further detail https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Why not download it, make it smaller, and then delete the old version?

Comment: i can't access the server that provides me the images, it's API.

Comment: Download it to your app, make it smaller, and delete the old version to save space.